# Calling Stored procedure through Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, stored-procedures

How can i access Stored procedure created in Mysql through rails code?
I am currently using following versions for rails application:-

Rails 2.1.0
Ruby Enterprise Edition 2010.01

Thanks....

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498331/how-to-call-mysql-stored-procedure-from-rails

Comment: This is not working with **Rails-3 + Ruby-1.9.2**

Comment: No Manish, It is working with your mentioned version, In my current project it is working fine. You just check the syntax of your stored procedure...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this below:
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("call sp_name(param1,param2,.....)")