# Rails execute stored procedure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stored-procedures

I am trying to execute the **oracle stored procedure** from **rails console**. Using the following code

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("execute change_name('shanison', 'shanison_test');
```

And keep getting the following error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: OCIError: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement: execute si.change_name('shanison', 'shanison_test');
```

I tried to run the query directly in the **oracle sql developer** and it worked fine, which means **my stored procedure is fine**.

```
execute change_name('shanison', 'shanison_test');
```

I did grant the Execute permission to the database users that the rails I'm using. I have tried running this under Rails 2 and 3, both doesn't work and shows the same error message.

Answer (score 3):

The following statement works:

```
OracleTableBase.connection.execute("begin change_user_name('shanison', 'shanison_test');end;")
```

Although a lot of document shows that using exec, or call should be working. [Calling Stored procedure through Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779400/calling-stored-procedure-through-rails)

Comment: Found this call vs exec http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/81939/2/. It seems that exec is only available to SQLPlus. So it is not really a valid sql if you are not calling from the SQL Plus.