# Call to a stored procedure in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am calling a stored procedure that returns several results.

In Rails 4, the only solution found is to initiate a new `Mysql2::Client` with the flag MULTI_STATEMENTS. It seems not right to me to open a new connection to the database server.

```
options = Rails.application.config_for(:database).merge flags: Mysql2::Client::MULTI_STATEMENTS
client = Mysql2::Client.new options
results = client.query %Q{CALL my_proc('#{params}')}
client.close

results
```

So my question: is there a better solution as of now?

Comment: Have you tried what suggested here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498331/how-to-call-mysql-stored-procedure-from-rails

Comment: Thanks @SimoneCarletti, I could not find the anwser you linked before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to call the stored proc with `exec_query` then to `clear_active_connections!` like this:

```
results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query %Q{CALL my_proc('#{params}')}
ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections!

results
```